# macOS: Intents Extension for Shortcuts opens main app and does not run for itself

Tags: xcode, macos, sirishortcuts, macos-monterey

I am trying to create an Intents Extension for macOS 12 Monterey.

What I've done:

- I've created an Intents Definition file and configured a Custom Intent
- I've created a Handler class that confirms to my Handling protocol that has been created by Xcode using the Intent Definition
- I've added an Intents Extension as a new target that creates my Handler class in `func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any`

**Problem:**

My shortcut action does appear in Shortcuts. However, ever time I run a shortcut with my action, the main app launches and not the extension itself.

I've been able to figure out what I was doing wrong, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found two possible causes for this:

1. Do **not** add your Intent to Supported Intents of your main app (`info.plist`) as you only have to do this if you want your main app to handle the intent via `func application(_ application: NSApplication, handlerFor intent: INIntent) -> Any?`. in the app delegate (a.k.a. in-app handling) - you want your extension to handle the intent
2. By default Intent Extensions aren't sandboxed. So you have to enable `App Sandbox` in the build settings and add an entitlements file with `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` set to `true`. Apple should really do this for any new Intent Extension by default.
3. When adding a new target for your *Intent Extension*, make sure not to select *App Intent Extension*. [image]

Cheers!

Comment: When I create an Intents extension, I keep getting the following error: "Provisioning profile "Mac Team Provisioning Profile: com.myapp.blah" doesn't include the aps-environment and com.apple.developer.siri entitlements". I've tried adding the entitlements as well, but doesn't help. I have "Automatically Manage Signing" enabled.

Comment: After many hours, I finally figured it out. When I created the Intents extension, for *some bizarre reason*, Xcode decided to lift the entitlements from the iOS app's target's entitlements file instead of from the Mac app target. I had to switch them back in build settings, and automatic provisioning works again.

Comment: Exactly this! I spent several hours trying to figure out why it does not work even though it was listed in shortcuts. I had error "Is your intent listed in IntentsSupported in the extension Info.plist?" - hopefully more people will find your answer - thanks!